# Is it legal and safe to take off or land in zero visibility?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, takeoff

Is it legal for planes to takeoff and land in zero visibility? Is it safe?

Comment: Why the downvote, downvoter? This is a solid question and one which CFIIs cover during training.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the US, for general aviation flights, operating under [Part 91 of the FARs](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=3efaad1b0a259d4e48f1150a34d1aa77&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14), it is legal to take off with zero visibility ([see page 2-2 of the IPH](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/media/CH-02.pdf), PDF). In my opinion, **it is not safe.** If an emergency were to take place, you would be unable to return and land; under Part 91, it is *not* legal to land unless conditions are equal to or better than a runway's published approach minimums.

Unless you've got a great alternate nearby, conditions are improving rapidly, or you've got an extra engine or two, you probably shouldn't take off in conditions you couldn't land in.

Comment: You might want to clarify what "part 91" means in this context, it's not obvious to many people.

Comment: Good call. Fixed some wording and added links to 91 and the Instrument Procedures Handbook.

Comment: The update is good, but what I was really thinking is that "part 91" is US only, so for many readers it might be clearer to just refer to "general aviation" instead?

Comment: This is definitely a case of "What is safe is not always legal ; What is legal is not always safe!" -- There's a reason most pilots won't opt for a "zero-zero" takeoff. My instructors always drilled into my head that you don't take off unless you're darn sure you can turn around and land again in you get into an emergency situation. (And the stuff I fly in isn't equipped for Category IIIc ILS approaches :-)

Comment: @Pondlife Actually it would be interesting if someone from another country/region could chime in and tell us if they have different requirements there (like "You can't take off unless you could legally make an approach to the field you just left")

Comment: @Pondlife rephrased to "for general aviation flights", which I agree is more useful. Also, I'd love to see non-US answers to this question.

Comment: Yes, some non-US answers would be great and they would really help us get a grip on the whole question of country-specific answers and regulations

Comment: IMO, a zero-zero takeoff in a twin would be more dangerous than in a single.  Loss of control on/just above the runway if you lose an engine on takeoff is busy enough when you can see fine.  With no visibility it's going to be a very ugly event.  I'd rather glide into a tree in a dead single.  :-)

Comment: Also, Cat III ILS approach minimums are close to zero visibility (75m or so), and is what some people call zero visibility.

Comment: @xpda, while true, most GA pilots can't fly Cat III approaches. I tried to make my answer as relevant as possible to GA. I don't see why there wouldn't be room for an additional answer about airline operations, though.

Comment: I hadn't gotten the hours I needed flying for the US Navy to take off with 0 visibility and 0 ceiling.  I asked an old timer why he had it and he said that, "They gave it to me because they new I would never use it."